# Combing rows in a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I have an input as below:

```
sno name    time
1   hello   1
1   hello   2
1   hai 3
1   hai 4
1   hai 5
1   how 6
1   how 7
1   are 8
1   are 9
1   how 10
1   how 11
1   are 12
1   are 13
1   are 14
```

I want to combine the fields having similar values in name as the below output format:

```
sno name timestart timeend
1 hello 1 2
1 hai 3 5
1 how 6 7
1 are 8 9
1 how 10 11
1 are 12 14
```

The input will be sorted according to time and only the records which are having the same name for repeated time intervals must be merged.
I am trying to do using spark but I cannot figure out a way to do this using spark functions since I am new to spark. Any suggestions on the approach will be appreciated.

I tried thinking of writing a user-defined function and applying maps to the data frame but I could not come up with the right logic for the function.

PS: I am trying to do this using scala spark.

Comment: You should include what you've tried so far?

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you happen to know the correct self-join query to do this? Or if you have any resources that would be great too.

Comment: a simple groupBy and aggregation function should solve it but we need to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: I think `RDD` and `aggregateByKey` will be a far better choice then DataFrames for this one

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so would be to use a plain SQL query.
Let's say `df` is your input dataframe.

```
val viewName = s"dataframe"
df.createOrReplaceTempView(viewName)
spark.sql(query(viewName))

def query(viewName: String): String = s"SELECT sno, name, MAX(time) AS timeend, MIN(time) AS timestart FROM $viewName GROUP BY name"
```

You can of course use df set. This would be something like:

```
df.groupBy($"name")
  .agg($"sno", $"name", max($"time").as("timeend"), min($"time").as("timestart"))
```

Comment: When cricket_007 suggested me to try joins i had the same query in mind. But the problem with this query is : 
In the example that i gave, if we apply this query, for the name "are" it would return result as only 1 row 
1 are 8 14
where as i am only looking to join the rows which are continuous and have the values repeated.